# Kafka Tool connection issues w/ kafka image running on Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I followed the example provided here: https://codeopinion.com/getting-started-apache-kafka-with-net-core/
and the following comamnds:

1. `docker network create kafka`
2. `docker run -d --network=kafka --name=zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 -e ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000 -p 2181:2181  confluentinc/cp-zookeeper`
3. `docker run -d --network=kafka --name=kafka -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 -p 9092:9092  confluentinc/cp-kafka`

I am able to use Kafa tool to connect to instance, but when a message is send nothing is coming thru.

I read up on advertised listeners and did the following:

```
docker run -d --network=kafka --name=bf-kafka -p 9092:9092 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=bf-zookeeper:2181 -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes -e KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092 -e KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false confluentinc/cp-kafka
```

NOTE: I am setting KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE to flase because my message format is {api}.{domain}.{action}.{version} format.

**ONE THIS TO NOTE:**
When I ran the commands on Mac, everything works fine. Kafka tool is able receive the message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try just setting `KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`

Comment: so remove KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS and just do KAFA_LISTENERS?

Comment: yep, give it a shot. the other option is to set an entry on /etc/hosts - `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx kafka` and set that in the server.properties. Then, from the clients, also call `kafka:9092`

Comment: negative.. adding KAFKA_LISENERS doesn't work

Comment: Okay found the solution..  for the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS you have to set the ip to your computer's ip address not localhost! This seems to work!

https://youtu.be/jY5fzVCkABg?t=228

Comment: @aran Please don't suggest to edit the hosts file. Properly setting the advertised listeners is the correct solution

Comment: Btw, ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER is a property of bitnami containers, not Confluent

Comment: updated my info, you are right, no needed anymore (/etc/hosts)